# Python IDE and gathering runtime statistics (variable types and other)

Tags: python, ide, statistics, runtime, variable-types

It occured to me after reading this blog post and watching related video: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/05/dynamic-languages-strike-back.html

Is there any Python IDE that gathers Python program runtime statistics and uses it to provide better code completion, variable type determining etc.?

Or, if not IDE, is there any working tool that gathers such information and can be used by programmer to do something useful?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no tool that is able to do all this magic at once, but...

- eclipse can do some inference about basic types, e.g. classes and instance members, functions, can do some autocompletion
- semantic & emacs also does it
- pywin, IDLE and pycrust introspect imported modules, also providing autocompletion
- pylint does extensive static checks, apart from other functionality